# Confused on ER examples

Tags: sql, entity-relationship

So I'm a bit confused on how ER diagram relationships work. The examples provided by my professor are a bit confusing (we don't use crows feet notation) so I was wondering if anyone could help me understand it better.

[Here's the example image I'm referencing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FjG0N.png)

So this *was* my understanding of it, with the MANY-to-MANY relationship.

ONE A (1... from A's side) participates with ONE OR MORE B's (...N from B's side)

ONE B (1... from B's side) participates with ONE OR MORE A's (...N from A's side)

But then looking at the ONE-to-ONE optional example, this concept wouldn't work.

I thought that looking at it you'd go left to right. As in, A 1 to ...N B is a one to many relationship, where 1 is from A's side and N is from B's side? Clearly I'm a bit lost, so could someone help clear this up for me? All of the examples I've seen have been crows feet notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are reading that notation wrongly.

The 1..N on the A side doesnt mean 1A to Many B, it means "1 or more A". If you want to see how many B it refers to, thats on the right side.

So your professor's diagram always has the x..y referring to the number of tuples on that side of the diagram only.

Make sense?

```
1..1 means exactly 1
1..n means one or more
0..1 means zero or 1
0..n means 0 or more
```

Comment: So for the second example in the picture, why is it not: ONE A participates with ONE OR MORE B's, But ONE OR MORE B's participates with exactly ONE A? Because looking at it from B's side, it's 1..N so shouldn't that mean ONE MORE MORE B's to A?

Comment: In the descriptions its looking at it from the point of view of each A or B. So each A is 1..n B, while each B is exactly 1 A. I guess to make the descriptions clearer , where its 0..1, it could say `One B, if it exists, participates with...`

Comment: Thank you that actually helped a lot with clearing it up